# Multiple inheritance in java through interfaces

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance, extends, implements

i want to inherit singly, circular & doubly linked lists in a parent class "list".
Each class has its own interface.i first inherited singly, doubly & circular interface in a "list" interface then implemented that interface in my parent class "List".

please tell me the correct and good format how should i inherit three child classes in single parent class using java.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure that understood your final goal but saying briefly you have 3 opportunities:

1. Your result class C inherits B and A which contain the methods needed (don't forget that in this case C should be logically a "type of B" and B should be a "type of A")
2. You can use the Java 8 default methods in interfaces that will contain
   implementations of your methods

I hope this helps.